# SAP Hana - STRING_AGG issue with ORDER BY CLAUSE

Tags: aggregate-functions, window-functions, hana

We are currently facing an issue with [Window Functions](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3/content.htm) in SAP Hana SPS12.

One of our error is when we are using `STRING_AGG` function.

Here is the code :

```
/*
CREATE TABLE TEST_STR_AGG (
     GROUP_ID varchar(1)
     , CLASS_ID varchar(5)
     , MEMBER varchar(5)
);
*/

TRUNCATE TABLE TEST_STR_AGG;

INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX1', 'A0001');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX1', 'A0002');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX1', 'A0003');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX2', 'A0004');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX2', 'A0005');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('A', 'A_XX3', 'A0006');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX1', 'B0001');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX2', 'B0002');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX3', 'B0003');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX4', 'B0004');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX4', 'B0005');
INSERT INTO TEST_STR_AGG VALUES ('B', 'B_XX4', 'B0006');

SELECT GROUP_ID
    , CLASS_ID
    , STRING_AGG( MEMBER, ' ; '  **ORDER BY MEMBER ASC** ) as MEMBERS
FROM TEST_STR_AGG
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
    , CLASS_ID ;
```

The `STRING_AGG` used to work perfectly with an `ORDER BY` clause before a patch install. Now, it is only working with a little volume of lines, as it works in the example I'm giving you. When we are working on more than 500k lines, some lines are disappearring from our result **if we add the `ORDER BY` clause in the `STRING_AGG`**. If we're not, it works.
We have the same issue on `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` functions.

It seems to be a core optimization rule which is corrupting the results...

Does anybody know something about this, please ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's a known bug. Don't have the SAP note ready right now, but it's fixed in a current revision.

/--
Found the SAP note for this:

2365540 - Aggregation Function AVG() Returns ? / NULL Values When Used in Combination With STRING_AGG Including an ORDER BY Clause

> Solution
>   Apply SAP HANA database Revision >= 112.07 (SPS11) or >= 122.02 (SPS12).

--/

Comment: In fact, we started to have this bug since we applied 122.02, on 23th of september) ! And it is not linked to the combination of 2 aggregation functions, but only one on a big set of lines.

Comment: In that case you should open a support incident to get a fix in a newer revision.

Comment: "Order By" works as Lars mentioned on a database running on version 1.00.122.04